# Деление в C++

Tags: c++

Как разделить в C++ 100 на 2000 , чтобы получить значение 0.05 ?

Comment: float x = 100. / 2000.;

Comment: Вдает 0, а мне нужно  0.05.

Comment: а вы точно сделали как я написал? т.к. у меня все работает.

Comment: @Андрей2, почитайте хоть учебник что ли

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   std::cout<<100./2000.;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо , точки не заметил.